# Put dash after every n character with country code +1 during input from keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('.creditCardText').keyup(function() {
  var foo = $(this).val().split("-").join(""); // remove hyphens
  if (foo.length > 0) {
    foo = foo.match(new RegExp('.{1,4}', 'g')).join("-");
  }
  $(this).val(foo);
});
```

I found this tutorial on putting dash after every 4 character from here my question is what if the character interval is not constant like in this example it is only after every 4 what if the interval is 3 characters "-" 3 characters "-" 4 characters so it would appear like this +1 123-123-1234 with country code +1.

Comment: If a user goes to fix a number (by deleting characters etc...) he will for sure go mad at the developer who programmed that silly input UX that got him stuck in the dash editing loop. I suggest you don't put your address in the codebase comments. He will find you. And he will

Comment: Also, by using only the "keyup" EventName, you're forgetting that one can just copy/paste a value into that input. And nothing will happen.

Answer (score -1):

I found this solution using an `if else` statement.

```js
function autoDash(f)
            {
                length = f.value.length;
                if(length<1){
                    f.value="+1-"+f.value;
                }
                else if(length == 6){
                    f.value=f.value+"-";
                }
                else if(length == 10){
                    f.value=f.value+"-";
                }
        }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="tel" name="tel" maxlength="15" onkeydown="autoDash(this)" />
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, the **how** is important, but much of the site's quality level comes from people going out of their way to explain **why**. While a _code-only_ answer get the person who asked the question past whatever hurdle they might be facing, it doesn't do them or future visitors much good in the long run. See [Is there any benefit in code-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/183937)

Comment: Never **ever** tap into an user-active input using .val() or .value while the user is editing (*keyup* etc.). UX 101.